# postgres user's watchbog command taking 100% CPU constantly

Tags: postgresql

I have installed postgre on Ubuntu 16.04 with postgres user, and after running my application for a couple of days, I am observing the CPU usage from `watchbog` command is 100% constantly forever untill i restart the server.

I have checked running queries in `pg_stat_activity` there are no queries running.

Following is from top

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
9964 postgres  20   0  619320  14368   4028 S 399.0  0.1 102527:09 watchbog
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've been hacked.  Watchbog is a name known to be used by malware, and is unused by PostgreSQL itself.  They may have come in through your database server and leveraged that to run commands in the OS as 'postgres', or maybe they just hacked into the OS account named 'postgres' directly.